# navbar not working when updating bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha to newer version

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have a little project to try to learn some Angular and after a few months when I did not have time to work on it I got it back now.
First I wanted to update my version of bootstrap but I am getting some problems with the navigation bar.
My navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" routerLinkActive="active">{{menuItem.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.xing.com"><i class="fa fa-xing-square socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://stackexchange.com/"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-default my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here my current working libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am trying to update to the official ones provided here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/

When I update the libraries my navbar does not work at all, it only shows a link on the right top corner with the title "navbar".
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the [latest Navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/). The structure and classes have changed since alpha. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676358/171456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply change `navbar-toggleable-md` to `navbar-expand-md` and for add colors, change `navbar-inverse bg-inverse` to `navbar-dark bg-dark`.

your burger-menu is `left side` you can change into right side by add `anchor tag` before button

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" routerLinkActive="active">{{menuItem.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.xing.com"><i class="fa fa-xing-square socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://stackexchange.com/"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow socialIcons" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-default my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'm pretty sure that You should realy read this first.

[Bootstrap 4, bg-inverse not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485768/bootstrap-4-bg-inverse-not-showing)

Comment: thanks for you answer. I was not able to recognize that my problem is there. I got back to my project after a few months and when I update I get that problem... from my point of view it could have been anything but good that you know it :)