# Toggle button already collapsed even when not clicked yet

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, togglebutton

so here's the code I'm working with, but the problem is when I collapse the browser the item inside the toggle button is already shown without me clicking it. I already check the others post here with the same problem but they aren't working the jquery, tether, and bootstrap are all in their right places so I don't get why it isn't working.

btw. I'm using an outdated alpha release of bootstrap 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
<body>
```

```
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Cute</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Announcements<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Calendar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G0yT.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question?-  [Bootstrap 4 toggleable navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676291/bootstrap-4-toggleable-navbar)

Comment: @Tanim Tried it but doesn't work. when I tried the solution on the link you provided, the toggle item has been shown even when I'm not resizing the output window into a smaller size.